# c# SelectMany, gather information from a nested model in a list

Tags: c#, linq, bamboo

I am working on a project and I am trying to clean up some code. I can get the information I need using 2 lines, however I am new to using SelectMany and figure maybe I am looking at this wrong. So what I'd like to to take my two lines of code and turn it into 1 line of code if at all possible.

Selecting: I need the BambooDeployModel by a particular name, in the example 'test' is the variable for this. 
Then once it narrows down my list to a particular model, I need to select the "Test" environment by name.

Here are my lines as is:

```
List<BambooDeployModel> deployments
var q = deployments.SelectMany(b => b.environments.Where(f => f.name ==    "Test"), (b, f) => f).SelectMany(f => deployments.Where(o => o.name == test)).Distinct();
var p = q.SelectMany(b => b.environments).Where(f => f.name == "Test").Distinct();
```

And here is the model, it is just a generic model based on values received from Bamboo based on deployments in our system.

```
public class BambooDeployModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public GenericSetKey key { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public GenericSetKey planKey { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<Environment> environments { get; set; }
    public Operations operations { get; set; }
}
public class GenericSetKey
{
    public KeyValuePair<string, string> key { get; set; }
}
public class Environment
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public GenericSetKey key { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int deploymentProjectId { get; set; }
    public Operations operations { get; set; }
    public string position { get; set; }
    public string configurationState { get; set; }
}
public class Operations
{
    public bool canView { get; set; }
    public bool canEdit { get; set; }
    public bool canDelete { get; set; }
    public bool allowedToExecute { get; set; }
    public bool canExecute { get; set; }
    public bool allowedToCreateVersion { get; set; }
    public bool allowedToSetVersionStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `SelectMany` that doesn't even use the item passed in `SelectMany(f => deployments.Where(o => o.name == test))` in this case `f`?   That combined with the `Distinct` basically renders the first `SelectMany` pointless.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you just want `deployments.Where(d => d.name == test).SelectMany(d => d.environments).Where(e => e.name == "Test");`  Not really clear if you need a `Distinct` after that, but it shouldn't hurt.

Comment: Those were my first attempts at getting anything to work. It worked, so I left it as is until now. It's crud, I know. Which is why Im trying to get the answer here.

Your second comment did the trick though, thank you!